# What kind of format does custom attribute blobs(strings) use?

Tags: .net, attributes, blob, il

So, I'm trying to figure out exactly how custom attributes with blobs work. The binary format seems very... odd.

Example from ildasm

```
.custom instance void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute::.ctor(string) = 
       ( 01 00 19 57 69 6E 64 6F 77 73 50 68 6F 6E 65 2C   // ...WindowsPhone,
        56 65 72 73 69 6F 6E 3D 76 38 2E 30 01 00 54 0E   // Version=v8.0..T.
        14 46 72 61 6D 65 77 6F 72 6B 44 69 73 70 6C 61   // .FrameworkDispla
        79 4E 61 6D 65 11 57 69 6E 64 6F 77 73 20 50 68   // yName.Windows Ph
        6F 6E 65 20 38 2E 30 )                            // one 8.0
```

What kind of format is this in? I can't quite tell if this is true UTF-8 and why are the first two bytes 0x01 and 0x00?  Also, a decompiler will pick pick this up as the attribute:

```
[assembly: TargetFramework("WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0", FrameworkDisplayName = "Windows Phone 8.0")]
```

How exactly does all of this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format of this is laid out in the [ECMA Common Language Infrastructure standard](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf), specifically section II.22.10 titled "CustomAttribute : 0x0C" (page 216).

It starts the "This contains informative text only" section with:

> All binary values are stored in little-endian format...

And continues in point 6 with:

> 6. The following rules apply to the overall structure of the Value 'blob' (§II.23.3):
>
> - Prolog shall be 0x0001  [ERROR]

This is why you see the first bytes of `[ 0x01, 0x00 ]`.

The rest of the text goes on to specify how the rest is laid out, but it's all in the spec.

There's also an [in-depth analysis](http://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2011/06/03/anatomy-of-a-net-assembly-custom-attribute-encoding/) which shows how it's represented in the CLR and how that impacts the storage of the attribute blob.